# attaching dictionary object to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I would like to know if there is a way to attach a `NSDictionary` object to a cell that is displayed in a `UITableView`, so when a cell is selected I can access the `NSDictionary` attached to that tableviewcell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just make a subclass of the cell and add your dictionary. You can use a completely empty implementation as well:

```
// MyCell.h
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary* dictionary;

@end

// MyCell.m
@implementation MyCell
@end
```

Now, just make sure you set your cell class if you're using a storyboard, or register it if you're not, and then just set the dictionary when you dequeue it and read it when you get the cell back later.

Comment: great.. going to figure out how to subclass them now.. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this if you subclass a `UITableViewCell` and create a `NSDictionary` property in your custom cell.

Assuming you have set this property before somewhere, here's how you retrieve it when the cell is selected:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.dictionary); //replace "dictionary" by the name of the property you created in the subclass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should strive to decouple the data model (NSDictionary) from the view (MyCell).  That's what the view controller is for - to manage the relationship between each cell and the data.

Your data model would typically be an NSArray.  Each element in the array corresponds to a row in the table (the indexPath).  Each NSArray element would hold an NSDictionary object (the data model) for each cell.